# Visual Studio 2017 platform toolset issue

Tags: visual-studio-2017

just wondering if anyone might be able to help with an issue I'm having with Visual Studio 2017. I originally had Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed with a valid key. Just recently I decided to just use Visual Studio 2017 Community because I'm not really using any of the features in Ultimate. After installing VS2017 Community, I uninstalled VS2012. Now, whenever I create a new project I get the error:

`The "ConfigurationGeneral" rule is missing the "WindowsTargetPlayformVersion" property.`

So I have to click "OK" then edit the properties of my project to use "VS 2012 (v110)" for the Platform Toolset to get anything to compile. It tells me v141 is not installed. Also my IntelliSense doesn't seem to be working at all.

If I check the VS Installer, it says I have both v140 and v141 installed, so I'm thinking it might be a path issue? I've been Googling but nothing has helped. Any help with this and IntelliSense would be appreciated, thanks.

Installed Components:

```
VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop
VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
```

I tried doing a repair, but that didn't help.

This is what IntelliSense says:

`error : Designtime build failed for project '..\MyProject.vcxproj' configuration 'Debug|Win32'. IntelliSense might be unavailable.

**Set environment variable TRACEDESIGNTIME = true and restart Visual Studio to investigate.**`

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yesterday I seen the same issue with Intellisense, I've also followed recommendations (like reset settings, repair, etc), but it doesn't help me. After half-day of investigations, I've figured out that issue was in configuration of my project (in CMAKE script). You can check is Intellysense works on new project (just create based on one of template). If yes, than try to comment you code, compare configuration with default project, etc.